# Como consultar palavras abreviadas ou não sem diferencia-las, como RUA e R.?

Tags: mysql

O usuário insere como pesquisa "RUA DO BATENTE".
Porém no banco de dados Mysql pode estar salvo como "R. Do Batente" ou só "BATENTE".

Como otimizar essa pesquisa para conseguir o melhor resultado, ou o mais aproximado ?

Comment: Coloca um trecho da sua consulta.

Comment: De imediato e a grosso modo: Quebre a string informada e faça uma pesquisa por todas as partes dela.

Comment: Pesquise também http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: tenta assim ó `SELECT [listadecampos, separados, por, virgula] FROM lista de tabelas separadas por espaço WHERE campoququerpesquisar LIKE '%palavrabuscadapelousuario%';` que vai retornar tudo que houver no campo contendo a palavra buscada, voce pode tratar a palavra antes de gerar a query ou pode usar as propias funcionalidades do mysql, tais como UPPER, e outras

Comment: Eu votei por deixar aberta, porque a pergunta me parece muito clara, o problema no máximo é que ela deve ser duplicata, mas até então não encontrei a tal possivel duplicata, então votei por deixa aberta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu não sei qual o impacto de se usar RegEx, mas parece um caso de uso, por exemplo:

```
SELECT nome_rua FROM enderecos WHERE LOWER(nome_rua) REGEXP '(rua\s+|r\.\s+)BATENTE'
```

Outra maneira que você pode fazer é um tratamento da string de consulta antes de envia-la, por exemplo:

```
$consulta = 'RUA BATENTE';

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT nome_rua FROM enderecos WHERE nome_rua LIKE ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $consulta);

//Limpa a consulta
$consulta = '%'.preg_replace('#^(r\.|av\.|rua|avenida|via)\s+#i', '', $consulta);

$stmt->execute();
```

Nesse exemplo acima usando `preg_replace`, nós removemos todos prefixos, como rua, avenida, av., r. e via, você ainda poderá adicionar mais coisas para remover e adicionei o coringa (sinal de `%`) no começo do `LIKE` para acaso tiverem outras palavras que gera algo como:

```
SELECT nome_rua FROM enderecos WHERE nome_rua LIKE '%BATENTE'
```

Também pode-se fazer isto:

```
//Limpa a consulta
$consulta = '%' . preg_replace('#^(r\.|av\.|rua|avenida|via)\s+#i', '', $consulta) . '%';
```

Que gera algo como:

```
SELECT nome_rua FROM enderecos WHERE nome_rua LIKE '%BATENTE%'
```